# How to push an element into an array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, push

I need to write a function that:

1. Goes through all numbers from 50 to 100
2. Checks what numbers are divisible by 6
3. Adds those numbers to an array
4. Writes that array
5. Writes how many elements there are in that array

I've searched for a function push in c++ but looks like there is none...

Got this far, doesnt wok...

```
int pushIntoArray(int array[], int size){
    int index = 0;
    int newArray[100];

    for (int i=0; i<=size; i++){
        if(array[i] % 6 == 0 && array[i] <= 100 && array[i] >= 50){
            newArray[index] = array[i];
            index++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a `std::vector`.

Comment: You're looking for `std::vector<int>`.

Comment: Do you have to use an array?  Also do you really need to even store them as it is easy to calculate on the fly.

Comment: What do You mean by _doesn't work_?

Comment: Using an array? You don't. As for your problem, what do you mean that it "doesn't work"? Can you please elaborate? And please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Yes, this is an assignment about arrays soo.. :D

Comment: i<=size should be i<size

Comment: By "doesnt work" i mean its not complete.

Comment: Thanks everyone :D

Comment: Your function is declared to return `int`, but doesn't return a value - that yields undefined behavior. Either declare it to return `void` or make sure that you `return` a value.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. Arrays ir C++ (and C too) are fixed-size. And for a good reason too. They are a very low level concept, quite similar to a pointer. The memory for an array is allocated once, at the start, and doesn't change after that. An array is just a bunch of bytes in memory.

A "push" operation would require to change the size of the array, which would mean allocating new memory, copying the contents from the old one, and deleting the old memory. And that's the simple, non-optimized version.

So, no, an array cannot do this. However the standard library includes a [`std::vector`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9xd04bzs.aspx) class which does exactly that and more. That's the one you want.

Comment: Good answer generally, but I think it's a little dangerous to say that an array is either "more than" or "less than" a pointer. They are just different things, one is not a weaker form of the other.

Comment: Well... I guess. OK, I'll try to reword it.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comment, when the size of an arrays isn't fixed, use `std::vector`

And use tham like in the code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> pushIntoVector(std::vector<int> values) {
    std::vector<int> result; //A vector of integers

    for (int a : values) // Goes through each values of the vector   
       if (a <= 100 && a >= 50 && !(a % 6)) {
            std::cout << a << "\n";
            result.push_back(a);
        }
    std::cout << result.size() << "\n";
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec;
    vec.push_back(36); //Not printed: < 50
    vec.push_back(60); //Printed
    vec.push_back(72); //Printed
    vec.push_back(90); //Printed
    vec.push_back(91); //Not printed: 91%6 != 0
    vec.push_back(105); //Not printed: > 100

    pushIntoVector(vec); //Do whatever you want with the returned vector
    while (1);
    return 0;
}
```